# What is constraining the Kullback-Leibler divergence to not be infinitely negative?

Tags: probability, entropy

I'm trying to understand t-SNE, based on [this video](https://youtu.be/RJVL80Gg3lA?t=900), and everything is clear except for one key part of the logic right at the time point linked to above: namely, minimizing the Kullback-Leibler divergence.

The stated problem is that we want to choose $ q_{ij} $ such that
$$
\sum\limits_{i}\sum\limits_{j \neq i} p_{ij} {\rm log} \left( \frac{p_{ij}}{q_{ij}} \right)
$$ is as small as possible, and

$$
q_{ij}=\frac{(1+|y_i-y_j|^2)^{-1}}{ \sum\limits_{k} \sum\limits_{l\neq k} \left( 1+|y_{k}-y_{l}|^2 \right)^{-1}}
$$

(I'm a little unsure about those $^{-1}$ exponents in the expression, but I'm copying what's in the video)(**Edit:** *they're right. The quantities are weighted inversely to squared distances*)

I understand that $q_{ij}$ is constrained to the range $0..1$, but ... these aren't probabilities (**Edit:** *They actually are referred to as "probabilities of choosing each other as neighbours"*), they're just normalized distances, so why is this a sensible comparison? does this just work for any set of numbers that are confined to the 0..1 range and which add up to one?

(I updated this question because I missed something obvious, but I'm still stuck. Thanks for any help you can offer)

Comment: Are $p_{ij}$ probabilities ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. As a function of $q_i \in (0,1]$, the term in the KL distance function can never become too negative, since $\sum_i p_i \log (p_i/q_i) = \sum_i p_i \log p_i - \sum_i p_i \log q_i$. The first term is a fixed negative number and you are subtracting a negative number. This is true even if the $q_i$ do not sum to 1.

Comment: That does help to clarify, thanks. One thing though:
"This is true even if the  do not sum to 1", yes, but in that case, minimization of the sum would be obtained by always choosing the largest possible $q$ value (i.e. $q_i=1 \forall i$, such that the negative number we subtract is always as close as possible to zero. )  The problem is only interesting If $q$ is constrained to sum to some finite value and must be doled out. Then it makes sense that you would want to arrange your largest $q$ values together with your largest $p$ values to "subtract the largest negative" each time.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, the following will help:

If $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are non-negative and $b_i > 0$, then the following holds

\begin{equation}
\sum_i a_i \log \left(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right) \ge \left(\sum_j a_j\right)\log \left(\frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_k b_k}\right).
\end{equation}

This inequality is called the log-sum inequality and is often encountered when studying information theory and high dimensional statistics.

In your case, $q_{ij}$ is positive and sums to 1, when summed over all $i$ and $j$, $j\ne i$. So it technically is a probability. As for whether RHS is non-negative or not depends on $p_{ij}$. I am assuming it is non-negative and not all zero.

Comment: > "So it technically is a probability."
Hmm, come to think of it, I think I actually have heard it referred to as "the probability of $i$ choosing $j$ as its neighbour" (assuming such a choice is inversely related to distance). So... yes, I suppose it is a probability in that sense. Thanks.